# keep md tab header position fixed on top

Tags: angularjs, material-design

I wonder how to make sure the header of the tab is kept top when scrolling vertically on some tab?

In this [example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oJwjGv), the second tab is long. When it is selected and user scroll down, the tab header goes up as well. I wonder how to make the header top fixed? I tried adding `style="position:top"`, but it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add this into your css

```
md-tabs-wrapper{ 
 position: fixed;
 background-color:#fff !important;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 z-index: 1000;
 width: 100%;
}


md-tabs.md-dynamic-height md-tabs-content-wrapper {
 top: 48px !important;
}
```

Working example on pen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pqwgLM

Comment: Thanks. But are you sure your code works? When I scroll down, the tab head goes up but not fixed...

Comment: Yes I just tested it works but I m browsing on chrome, which browser are u using ?

Comment: oh, I’m using my iPhone safari. I’ll check it when I get home.